# Is it ok to use TabActivity still for my app?

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-tabhost

My app is in need of some tabs and the TabActivity works great for it. It's much easier than wrapping my head around those Fragments... but I see that Android says to do Tabs in FragmentActivity now... My question is If I'm targetting 2.2 phones is it ok for me to use the TabActivity instead? Will I run into any issues in the future by making the app this way?

Comment: There are so many apps out there using Tabs, that I think Google will keep support for Tabs forever.

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended to use Fragments, i know it has an initial learning of few hours but its worth the effort. Use compatibility library for using fragments in Android versions lower than 11.